# chaining joins back to target table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables

```
Survey          Question        Responses       Participants
=============   ==============  ==============  =============
id_S            id_Q            id_R            id_P
                id_S            id_Q            id_S
                                id_P
                                id_S
                                Answer
```

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve all the Responses for the Participants who gave "D" as the answer for Question #3.

This is my first wack at it but unsurprisingly it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM responses r
LEFT JOIN participants p
ON r.id_P = p.id_P
LEFT JOIN responses r2
ON p.id_R = r.id_P
WHERE r.id_S = 1 AND r2.Answer = "D" AND r2.id_Q = 1
```

By doesn't work it returns too many records. The SQL `Select * FROM responses WHERE id_S =1` would return 1,891 records, but the above hot mess returns 15,128 records.

Clearly I don't even have the right concept of how to get this to work, and it's not a simple syntax tweak that's needed.

Comment: Divide it into two queries first (1) retrieve Participants who gave "D" as the answer for Question #3, and (2) retrieve all responses for participants in (1). Go from there

Comment: why you are doing left join with responses why not join this with Questions ?

Comment: You're asking "all the Responses for the Participants", not "all the Responses for the Participants in survey 1". I don't see why the former number could not be larger than all responses in survey 1.

Comment: @Oerd can that be done in the one SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  ra.*
FROM    responses rd
JOIN    responses ra
ON      (ra.id_s, ra.id_p) = (rd.id_s, rd.id_p)
WHERE   (rd.id_q, rd.answer) = (3, 'D')
```

Comment: Interesting, not seen that form of expression before. What is it called, so I can search for more to read up on it?

Comment: @Erics: what exactly are you speaking about?

Comment: (name1, name2) = (value1, value2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT r2.* 
FROM Responses r2
     INNER JOIN (Responses r
     INNER JOIN Question q ON r.id_Q = q.id_Q
     INNER JOIN Participants p ON p.id_P = r.id_P) r1 ON r2.id_P = r1.id_P
WHERE q.id_Q = 3
AND r.Answer = 'D';
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. What's the basic idea here though?