# More efficient SQL to eliminate multiple sub-queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL in my code and the repetition of the sub-queries has me worried that this isn't as efficiently written as it could be.

My database has a table for `features`, `responses`, and `participants`. Participants give a rating (one of D,P,B,I,R,Q) for each feature.

```
SELECT f.id, f.name,
(SELECT COUNT(r.id) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS nr_r, 
(SELECT SUM(r.is_D) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS is_D, 
(SELECT SUM(r.is_P) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS is_P, 
(SELECT SUM(r.is_B) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS is_B, 
(SELECT SUM(r.is_I) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS is_I, 
(SELECT SUM(r.is_R) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS is_R, 
(SELECT SUM(r.is_Q) FROM responses r LEFT JOIN participants p ON r.id_participant = p.id WHERE p.is_ignored IS NULL AND r.is_deleted IS NULL AND r.id_feature = f.id AND p.category LIKE :p_category) AS is_Q,
(SELECT (is_D + is_P)/(is_D + is_P + is_B + is_I)) as yay,
(SELECT (is_P + is_B)/(is_D + is_P + is_B + is_I)) as boo
FROM features f 
WHERE f.is_deleted IS NULL AND f.id_survey=:id_project
ORDER BY f.id ASC;
```

The output from that query is a table of totals, looking something like

```
577 App registration    989   36   21   38  201  42   6  0.1926  0.1993
578 Login PIN           989  279  118  137  394  41  20  0.4278  0.2748
579 Manage all services 989  287  207  127  331  23  14  0.5189  0.3508
580 Rewards             989  344  157   64  386  19  19  0.5268  0.2324
581 Offers              989  226   93   37  542  72  19  0.3552  0.1448
```

The query currently takes 4.4387 seconds to run for a dataset with 989 participants, 14 features (and thus 13,846 individual ratings). Pretty sure that stinks.

**Is there a more efficient way of writing that query?**

**Is this something that GROUP BY would be useful with?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query right you have the same predicates in every sub-query and then you can easily replace all sub-selects with a join and do a group by. The calculations on the aggregates (yay and boo) are calculated at the outer level:

```
SELECT id, name, nr_r, is_D, ...
     , (is_D + is_P)/(is_D + is_P + is_B + is_I) yay
     , (is_P + is_B)/(is_D + is_P + is_B + is_I) boo
FROM (
     SELECT f.id, f.name
         , count(r.id) AS nr_r
         , sum(r.is_D) as is_D
         , ...
     FROM features f
     LEFT JOIN responses r 
         ON r.id_feature = f.id
        AND r.is_deleted IS NULL 
     LEFT JOIN participants p 
         ON r.id_participant = p.id
        AND p.is_ignored IS NULL
        AND p.category LIKE :p_category  
     WHERE f.is_deleted IS NULL 
       AND f.id_survey=:id_project
     GROUP BY f.id, f.name
) AS T
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: If you want a `LEFT JOIN` then you should move the restrictions of the left joined tables from the `WHERE` clause to the join condition (i.e. `r.id_feature = f.id`) , because else you get implicitly `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: You are right, I did not look close enough at the query. It is alread in the join clause so it can be removed from the where clause. I'll update the answer

Comment: This is pretty close, but I'm getting wrong answers for the yay and boo columns - a bunch of 1.0, 0.0, and NULLs. I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Near as I can figure it's doing the calculation for yay and boo on individual response rows before the GROUP BY takes effect (only 1 of is_D/is_P/etc has a value 1, all others would be 0 or all would be NULL)

Comment: Yes it does, what you can do is to nest those calculations, I'll add that to my example.

Comment: @Lennart ah hah, I was just playing with a similar approach, but instead just nesting the the JOIN. This works, now I just have to roll in the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323094/chaining-joins-back-to-target-table/24333192 without my head exploding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56053/discussion-between-erics-and-lennart).